# C++ - rand() function not working, numbers do not go above 32,000

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to create random numbers from 0 to around 200,000, however the values do not go above 33,000. Even if I try a different value they still do not go above 33k. I tried to seed and still nothing. Did I miss something when I learned about this function? Thanks.

```
srand(time(0));
for (int count = 190000; count < 200000; count++)
    cout << rand() % 200001 << " ";
```

Comment: `rand` returns values between 0 and RAND_MAX. What is RAND_MAX?

Comment: ahh rand max is 32,767

Comment: Just write code to do exactly what you want. Don't expect `rand()` to understand your requirements. Actually, don't use `rand` at all.

Comment: I get it now thanks.

Comment: Consider using [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) instead of `rand`

Answer (score 2):

Make your range of values independent of the range of values `rand()` returns.

```
int getMyRandomNumber()
{
    static int MY_RANGE_MAX = 200001;
    return (1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX)*MY_RANGE_MAX;
}
```

and use it as:

```
for (int count = 190000; count < 200000; count++)
    cout << getMyRandomNumber() << " ";
```

Comment: If `RAND_MAX` is only 32,767 this won't select between 200000 numbers, only 32767 of them!

Comment: Read the code again, @Dithermaster. Pay special attention to `MY_RANGE_MAX`

Comment: @user4581301: However, since there are only 32768 possible values, it will not give 200000 different values, only 32768 different values. They will indeed be spread between 0 and 200000, but essentially each only one 6th of the possible values will be available. Which may be OK, or it may not, depending on what the requirement is.

Comment: Looking at it that way, I stand down. Apologies to @Dithermaster .

Comment: Thanks @MatsPetersson for the clear explanation, and thanks user4581301 for the apology. Random numbers are harder than most realize.